# Is it possible to have random access writes to a Google Drive file from the Android API?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, seek, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to record audio and create a wav file in Google Drive with the Android API. I have a first pass where I write the header with a file length of 0 bytes because I don't know how long the recorded audio will be and I don't want to keep it all in memory. Once the record is finished I seek back to byte 4 and write the length of the file.

This works great when using a RandomAccessFile but I can't figure out how to do something using the Google Drive API. https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files

The DriveContents class (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveContents) doesn't hint at any way to seek within the contents. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible this way. Google drive Apis ([V2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-sdk), [V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk), [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)) all accept `file streams` (i.e. serial streams) as contents. You are probably aware that you construct metadata + contents and upload (create, patch, update).

Since you need to modify `your file's header` after you're finished writing to the file, the only way to do it is to finish everything in a local file and then hand it's stream to the GooDrive Api. The update/patch will not help you in this case since your header is a part of a chunk of bytes known to GooDrive Apis as `contents`.

It is logical, V2 and V3 are straight REST apis, so they send the bytes up in a serial fashion. There is some hope GDAA may do it one day (see '[Lifecycle of a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files)'), but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 3):

Try using FileChannel for random access.

You can get the FileChannel with FileOutputStream#getChannel, then seek using FileChannel#position(long).
Writing to the OutputStream will then start from the set position.

Note: I would advise to flush the OutputStream before accessing the FileChannel.