# How to Update/Append Sqlite Database in Google drive

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-android-api

Well I have managed to upload and download my database to/from google drive using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853316/using-google-drive-to-backup-and-restore-sqlite-database) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602812/backup-restore-sqllite-database-to-google-drive-app-folder).

But now I want to update my sqlite data. Supposed I have uploaded data with 20 entries and then a user inserted 3 new ones. Now I just want to append these 3 new entries. I have searched but can't find any good solution.

Is it possible with google drive or should i move to another good syncing API like Firebase?

Any help or suggestion would be fine.

Comment: See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files#making_modifications).
Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514640/is-it-possible-to-have-random-access-writes-to-a-google-drive-file-from-the-andr) regarding random access to files might be useful.

Comment: well append will work perfect with insert but what about editing data

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514640/is-it-possible-to-have-random-access-writes-to-a-google-drive-file-from-the-andr/34538269#34538269) for a way to gain random access.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this, @HRaval ? Could you let me know, since I am having the same issue.

Comment: nope....for now i have managed it by deleting and uploading entire new db each time....i knew its not the best approach but i can't found any other